# what's the meaning for the TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, kernel

I know the TCP_SYN_RECV , however what's the meaning for the TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV? what's the difference between them?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5924bbecd0267d87c24110cbe2041b5075173a25/include/net/tcp_states.h

```
  enum {
    TCP_ESTABLISHED = 1,
    TCP_SYN_SENT,
    TCP_SYN_RECV,
    TCP_FIN_WAIT1,
    TCP_FIN_WAIT2,
    TCP_TIME_WAIT,
    TCP_CLOSE,
    TCP_CLOSE_WAIT,
    TCP_LAST_ACK,
    TCP_LISTEN,
    TCP_CLOSING,    /* Now a valid state */
    TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV,

    TCP_MAX_STATES  /* Leave at the end! */
};
```

Also I saw the following code "sk->sk_state == TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV" ,why not use "sk->sk_state == TCP_SYN_RECV" instead?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8fa3b6f9392bf6d90cb7b908e07bd90166639f0a/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L16485

```
if (sk->sk_state == TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV) {
    struct request_sock *req = inet_reqsk(sk);
    struct sock *nsk;
```

Comment: You can figure it out from corresponding commits. Use `git log -S'TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV' -- path/to/file/of/interest` in kernel sources directory to find out commits that added `TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV` to mentioned files. Read found commit messages to get a clue about new definition and its usage. Also, instead of github I'd suggest you to use mainline repo from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/) ([this one](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/)).

Comment: Great answer, I got it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this:

```
TCP_SYN_RECV state is currently used by fast open sockets.

Initial TCP requests (the pseudo sockets created when a SYN is received)
are not yet associated to a state. They are attached to their parent,
and the parent is in TCP_LISTEN state.

This commit adds TCP_NEW_SYN_RECV state, so that we can convert
TCP stack to a different schem gradually.
```

source, the author commit: http://git.kernel.org/linus/10feb428a504